# Typescript HTMLInputElement from getByLabelText

Tags: react-testing-library

Currently, if I do something like `const input = getByLabelText('Checked');` The type of input is HTMLElement.

However, if I try to do something like `expect(input.checked).toBe(true);` or `input.value` typescript gets sad because it's not of type `HTMLInputElement`. I'm wondering if I'm missing something or the types need to add a generic to do something like `getByLabelText<HTMLInputElement>()`

Answer (score 2):

I cast them as an HTMLInputElement, and it could probably be seen as a band-aid fix, but that's what it's for.

I'm a bigger fan of `const input = getByLabelText('Input') as HTMLInputElement` though, it's easier to see